# Segfault when entering Fortran subroutine

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran90

I am getting a segmentation fault when entering a subroutine.
In the debugger I can step until the first `call RK_sub_step` in the following code segment.
As soon as I step into the subroutine it segfaults.

```
module RK_mod

type(MyType), dimension(1:2) :: q0, q1, q2

contains

subroutine RK_sub_step(src, alpha, dest)
   real(8), dimension(:) :: alpha
   type(MyType), dimension(1:2,size(alpha)) :: src
   type(MyType), dimension(1:2), intent(inout) :: dest

   ! compute dest from alpha and src
end subroutine

subroutine RK()
    real(8) alpha(3)
    call RK_sub_step((/q0/), (/alpha(1)/), q1)    ! <- Segfault here
    call RK_sub_step((/q0, q1/), alpha(2:3), q2)
end subroutine

end module
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Edit:

Now I managed to circumvent the segfault by creating separate subroutines that I can call as

```
call RK_sub_step1(q0, alpha(1), q1)
call RK_sub_step2(q0, q1, alpha(2:3), q2)
call RK_sub_step4(q0, q1, q2, q3, alpha(4:8), q0)
```

But I still wonder, if it is possible to have only one subroutine like further above, or why this can not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that this

```
(/q0/)
```

constructs a rank-1 array of `myType` which, in the line which causes the segmentation fault, is passed to a subroutine which expects a rank-2 array of `myType` as its first argument.

`(/qo/)` does not, if `q0` is a rank-1 array, construct a rank-2 array.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could do two things to fit your desire of a single subroutine:

- Define `type(mytype), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: qtemp` and then allocate it to the right size (say `2,2`) and then set it using the loop

  ```
  do i=1,2
     qtemp(i,:) = (/q0(i), q1(i)/)
  enddo
  ```
- Write the different subroutines for the different number of input variables and then use an `interface` block -- [see here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/statements/interfac.html) or [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap06/interface.html) for help on those.